# Python Cannot see modification to objects mapped over a multiprocessing thread pool

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the below code I create a list of objects, spawn the list over a thread pool, to perform a function (modifying its state) on each object in parallel. After the thread pool I then loop over the objects and print the modification.

Unfortunately it's still printing the initial state.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = 0

def task_init(output_queue):
    task.output_queue = output_queue

def task(obj):
    obj.x = 5       # Here I change the value

my_list = []


obj = MyObj("")
my_list.append(obj)

output_queue = mp.Queue()

p = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count(), task_init, [output_queue])

p.map(task, my_list)

for obj in my_list:
    print(str(obj.x)) # Problem, shows the initial value, not 5
```

Comment: If you're using multiprocessing, your tasks are running *in another process*. They're not able to modify the memory of the parent process. It is possible to share some objects through [managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers), but you're often better off with a "share nothing" approach and passing messages back and forth via a queue.

Comment: @larsks thanks for the reply. Yes, realised that shortly.